# Create custom generic collection

Tags: c#, collections

I want to create a custom generic collection, which will store elements in `List<>` if there are less then 10 of them or in `SortedList<>` if there are more.

I implemented `ICollection(KeyValuePair)` for `SortedList<>` and `ICollection<>` for `List<>`, however I can't understand what should I do next. Could someone please give me a hint, how should implement the part 'store elements in `List<>` if there are less then 10 of them or in `SortedList<>` if there are more'?

```
class CustomCollection<T, V> : ICollection<KeyValuePair<T, V>>, ICollection<T>
    {
        private readonly ICollection<T> _list = new List<T>();
        private readonly ICollection<KeyValuePair<T, V>> _sortlist = new SortedList<T, V>();

        public void Add(KeyValuePair<T, V> item)
        {
            _sortlist.Add(item);
        }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            _list.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are solving this problem for an assignment, I think you misunderstood what the assignment wants you to do.

Comment: @dark You are doing it wrong. Your CustomCollection must probably use "transparently" the two inner collections, not show with methods what it's doing. You don't need two Add methods. You need one Add method that select where to add and, if adding the tenth/eleventh element, moves all the old elements to the other collection. And considering you are implementing a `SortedList<,>`, you should probably begin by implementing the IDictionary<,> interface

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies!
@xanatos Could you please provide an example of the "transparent" usage of the two inner collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is the full implementation. It is quite long, and **totally untested** :-) You can have fun debugging it.

There are some points of interest: the use of the two Comparer(s) (not a good idea), how the handling of `null` is done (it throws `NullReferenceException`, like the SortedList) and in the various `Add`, `Remove`, `Clear` how the switch between collections is done. Note that in general `SortedList` "hides" all the methods that handle directly the `KeyValuePair<,>`. I selected to do the same. Other note: to "search" in the `List<>` I do a linear search. Smarter (and faster) would be to do a `List.BinarySearch`.

```
public class CustomCollection<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    protected List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> List { get; set; }
    protected SortedList<TKey, TValue> SortedList { get; set; }

    // Two comparers needed: an EqualityComparer and a Comparer to sort
    // We could simply use the Comparer and compare the result to 0
    // instead of using an EqualityComparer and a Comparer
    protected readonly EqualityComparer<TKey> EqualityComparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    protected readonly Comparer<TKey> Comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;

    public int MaxCapacityList { get; protected set; }

    public CustomCollection(int maxCapacityList = 10)
    {
        MaxCapacityList = maxCapacityList;

        if (maxCapacityList > 0)
        {
            List = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
        }
        else
        {
            SortedList = new SortedList<TKey, TValue>();
        }
    }

    public bool IsUsingList
    {
        get
        {
            return List != null;
        }
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (IsUsingList)
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            if (List.Any(x => EqualityComparer.Equals(x.Key, key)))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }

        if (IsUsingList && List.Count < MaxCapacityList)
        {
            List.Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));

            // Only place we need to sort. Only "real" Add method
            List.Sort((x, y) => Comparer.Compare(x.Key, y.Key));
        }
        else
        {
            if (IsUsingList && List.Count == MaxCapacityList)
            {
                SortedList = new SortedList<TKey, TValue>();

                foreach (var kv in List)
                {
                    SortedList.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
                }

                List = null;
            }

            SortedList.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        if (IsUsingList)
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            if (List.Any(x => EqualityComparer.Equals(x.Key, key)))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        return SortedList.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsUsingList)
            {
                return List.ConvertAll(x => x.Key);
            }

            return SortedList.Keys;
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        if (IsUsingList)
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            for (int ix = 0; ix < List.Count; ix++)
            {
                if (EqualityComparer.Equals(List[ix].Key, key))
                {
                    List.RemoveAt(ix);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        bool result = SortedList.Remove(key);

        if (result && SortedList.Count == MaxCapacityList && MaxCapacityList > 0)
        {
            List = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();

            foreach (var kv in SortedList)
            {
                List.Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(kv.Key, kv.Value));
            }

            SortedList = null;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        if (IsUsingList)
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
            {
                if (EqualityComparer.Equals(List[i].Key, key))
                {
                    value = List[i].Value;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            value = default(TValue);
            return false;
        }

        return SortedList.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsUsingList)
            {
                return List.ConvertAll(x => x.Value);
            }

            return SortedList.Values;
        }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsUsingList)
            {
                if (key == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException();
                }

                for (int ix = 0; ix < List.Count; ix++)
                {
                    if (EqualityComparer.Equals(List[ix].Key, key))
                    {
                        return List[ix].Value;
                    }
                }

                throw new KeyNotFoundException();
            }

            return SortedList[key];
        }
        set
        {
            if (IsUsingList)
            {
                if (key == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException();
                }

                for (int ix = 0; ix < List.Count; ix++)
                {
                    if (EqualityComparer.Equals(List[ix].Key, key))
                    {
                        List[ix] = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                Add(key, value);

                return;
            }

            SortedList[key] = value;
        }
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        if (IsUsingList)
        {
            List.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            if (MaxCapacityList > 0)
            {
                List = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
                SortedList = null;
            }
            else
            {
                SortedList.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        if (IsUsingList)
        {
            if (item.Key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            return List.Any(x => EqualityComparer.Equals(x.Key, item.Key));
        }

        return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)SortedList).Contains(item);
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        if (IsUsingList)
        {
            List.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
            return;
        }

        ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)SortedList).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return IsUsingList ? List.Count : SortedList.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        if (IsUsingList)
        {
            if (item.Key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            for (int ix = 0; ix < List.Count; ix++)
            {
                if (EqualityComparer.Equals(List[ix].Key, item.Key))
                {
                    var comparer2 = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;

                    if (comparer2.Equals(List[ix].Value, item.Value))
                    {
                        List.RemoveAt(ix);
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        bool result = ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)SortedList).Remove(item);

        if (result && SortedList.Count == MaxCapacityList && MaxCapacityList > 0)
        {
            List = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();

            foreach (var kv in SortedList)
            {
                List.Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(kv.Key, kv.Value));
            }

            SortedList = null;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return IsUsingList ? List.GetEnumerator() : SortedList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Chained to the other GetEnumerator()
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```